# Apache Jena RDFWriter.setProperty has no effect

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena, apache-jena

I'm using Jena (apache-jena-libs 3.0.1) in my java application to create RDF model and serialize to RDF/XML. I am using the same way that is documented in https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File(dir, filename + ".xml") );
RDFWriter rdfWriter = notificationModel.getWriter("RDF/XML-ABBREV");
rdfWriter.setProperty("showXmlDeclaration", "true");
rdfWriter.setProperty("showDoctypeDeclaration", "true");
rdfWriter.write(notificationModel, out, null);
```

However, the writer ignores any of the properties, they have no effect on the resulting XML. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug (just record as JENA-1168)

A workaround is to use

```
RDFWriter rdfWriter = new org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmloutput.impl.Abbreviated() ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Link to the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1168